# Terminal Command to open applications on login

Tags: authentication, terminal, applescript

I have created an application for a prank on friends using AppleScript. The only thing I haven't managed to figure out is how to change the application contents to make the app automatically open at login. Is there a specific info.plist key I can use for this?

If not how can I get the application to change computer settings, when run, to open the application on login?

This is the script I put into an application. It is a `stay-open` app.

```
   property idleTime : 10 --seconds


on run

    idle

end run


on idle

    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if it is not running then return idleTime

        tell window 1 to if it exists then ¬
            tell its active tab
                set its URL to "chrome://newtab/"
            end tell
    end tell

    return idleTime

end idle
```

Answer (score 1):

To get an application to launch on system startup, you can go to *System Preferences > Users & Groups*; select the appropriate user; then select *Login Items*.  You'll see a screen like this:

[image: Login Items on MacOS]

Click the `+` button and select your application to be added to the list.  You'll probably want to select the checkbox to *hide* the application as well, so that it doesn't pop up on the screen.  This won't, however, hide it from the dock.

If you really need to set it programmatically for any reason, you can use AppleScript to do it.  For example, if I wanted to add *Calendar.app* to the list of start up items, I would run this command:

```
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        make new login item with properties ¬
        {name:"Calendar", path:"/Applications/Calendar.app", hidden:true}
```

To do so from *Terminal*, you'd run the same command using `osascript`, like this:

```
    osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to ¬' \
              -e 'make new login item with properties ¬' \
              -e '{name:"Calendar", path:"/Applications/Calendar.app", hidden:true}'
```